# Can't convert Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, Iterable<String>>

Tags: java, collections

Hi I have quiet a simple code that returns me an error

```
    void changeHeaders(HttpURLConnection url){
        Map<String, Iterable<String>> m ;
        m = url.getHeaderFields();//<-- this line gives an error
        ...
    }
```

The error is: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,List<String>> to Map<String,Iterable<String>>`

Why I can not convert List to Iterable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit

Answer (score 7):

Because of generics. You have to use something like:

```
Map<String, ? extends Iterable<String>> m;
```